# Parse string in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a semi colon delimited string variable in my stored procedure with contents shown in quotes below with a phrase and name separated by two dashes "--".

String Variable below.

```
Outside Hire--Hire #01; Reassignment - External--Hire #15; Reassignment - External--Hire #21; Outside Hire--Hire #03; Internal Reassignment--John Pen; Outside Hire--Kara Emma
```

I would like to parse it out such that it shows the names associated with each phrase in brackets, separated by a comma and the number of times the phrase occurs. Example of result is displayed below.

Result

```
3 Outside Hire(Hire #01, Hire #03, Kara Emma); 2 Reassignment - External(Hire #15, Hire #21); 1 Internal Reassignment(John Pen)
```

Comment: The real problem looks like you are storing delimited data in your RDBMS. Seems you really need tom fix the design, what ever it is.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. You're missing a few important items, e.g showing what you tried and including a _specific_ programming question. You don't have _any_ question.

Comment: Hi Larnu. I'll confess the contents of the string variable with semi colons as a delimiter isn't fancy but that is what I could craft after massaging data retrieved from a combination of tables. Semi colons are then stored in variable tables where it is queried further and then displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little ugly, but perhaps this will help

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'Outside Hire--Hire #01; Reassignment - External--Hire #15; Reassignment - External--Hire #21; Outside Hire--Hire #03; Internal Reassignment--John Pen; Outside Hire--Kara Emma'

;with cte as (
Select Cnt=sum(1) over (Partition By Pos1)
      ,Pos1
      ,Pos2
 From  string_split(@S,';') A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]'))
                      ,Pos2 = trim(JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]'))
                 From  ( values ( '["'+replace(replace(Value,'"','\"'),'--','","')+'"]' ) ) A(S)
             ) B
),  cte2 as (
Select Distinct TmpStr = concat(A.cnt,' ',Pos1,'(',Stuff((Select ', ' +Pos2 From cte Where Pos1=A.Pos1 For XML Path ('')),1,2,'') ,')') 
 From  cte A
)
Select NewStr = Stuff((Select '; '+TmpStr From cte2 order by TmpStr Desc For XML Path ('')),1,2,'')
```

**Returns**

```
NewStr
3 Outside Hire(Hire #01, Hire #03, Kara Emma); 2 Reassignment - External(Hire #15, Hire #21); 1 Internal Reassignment(John Pen)
```